# C# select dbf column names

Tags: c#, dbf

Is there a way to directly query the columns names of a DB4 .dbf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GetOleDbSchemaTable ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx)) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/52832194-3578-4f66-b4f9-37c0db26e6c5) you've got an example of using it for dbf file in VB, that should help you in getting proper connection.